# passing values between activities

Tags: android

Hello everyone I have the following code which is retreving some data from the server and when i click on any item it show me  the id which is retrieve from the server . Instead of showing in the toast i want to pass to another activity. here is the orginal code

```
public class Test extends ListActivity  {
      Prefs myprefs = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        this.myprefs = new Prefs(getApplicationContext());
        // install handler for processing gui update messages
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
       JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/proj/androidjson.php?identifier=" + 
        Test.this.myprefs.getPersonalno());

        try{

            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("services");

            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("pic", "Service name : " + e.getString("employeepic"));
                map.put("serviceinfo", "" +  e.getString("employeename")+ " : "+ e.getString("starttime")
                        +" To " +  e.getString("endtime"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                        new String[] { "servicename", "serviceinfo" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });

    }
```

I am trying to adjust this code but every time "Force to Close"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, passing.class);
intent.putExtra("Employename", employeename);
startActivity(intent);
```

for the id its done in the following way . but now how can replace it with employename

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, passing.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent); 

            }
        });

}
```

Comment: could you please post the the logcat... because this should do wat you r trying to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi umar i have a couple of questions to you... Have you tried inserting the starting new activity part in the place you have the toast statement. if so and after inserting that the force close dialog comes.. Please check whether you have the class with name passing and also defined a activity in the manifest... if you are still getting the force close anr just post your logcat which would help us to solve your problem..

Comment: for the id its done now i only want to put employename instead of id so please guide me about it

Comment: did you get the value in the toast from this statement. ` Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`